# How can I store items of a listbox into different rows of a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 list boxes in a form. 
The first listbox shows the rows from a table in the database. I used this code to display the rows as items in the listbox:

```
Private Sub Form_load
    Dim listbox1 as new Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select columname from table", cn)     
    Dim dt as new datatable()
    listbox.fill(dt)
    For a=0 to dt.Rows.Count -1
        Listbox.Items.Add(dt.Rows(a). Item(0))
    Next
End Sub
```

The items displayed in this listbox are selected and is displayed in another listbox. I need help on how to save the items on the selected listbox(second listbox) to another table's rows in a database

Answer (score 0):

As you said, listbox2 is our another listbox containing the items from listbox1

```
For temp As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            var = ListBox2.SelectedItems.Item(temp)
           'Saving item to another table for ex: insert into tab2 values(var);
           'Or update tab2 set foo = var where ....;
           '..ExecuteQuery()
        Next
```

here we are extracting data from listbox2 which is stored in var and respectively preparing and executing queries as well to save the items in the database.